# Should I post here or on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

With the recent split<sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014),[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250024/the-status-of-the-split),[3](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/)</sup> of Meta Stack Overflow into [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and a proper [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), I don't know where I should post.

If I have a question, feature request, or bug report that isn't totally specific to Drupal Answer, should I post here or on MSE?

Answer (score 5):

Meta Drupal Answers is *our* home for asking questions and discussing issues both with Drupal Answers itself, as well as network wide topics.

We should continue to use MDA to discuss topics specific to Drupal Answers, and we should continue to use MDA to shape what we want it to be (while keeping in the general guidelines and philosophy of the Stack Exchange sites).

People are free to bring up network wide issues directly on MSE, but those topics are perfectly acceptable here.  The SE developers and community managers will keep an eye out for bug reports and other posts, and handle them as needed.  We also have the ability to migrate posts to MSE when the situation warrants.